# How to completely replace schema in mongo document with mongoose

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-schema

For reasons I won’t get into, we have a need to be able to change the schema on which a document is based, that is, a document existing within mongo.

Here’s the problem I’m running into.

I have two schemas, let’s call them SchemaOne and SchemaTwo defined as:

```
const schemaOne = new mongoose.Schema({
  FirstName: { type: String, required: true },
  LastName: { type: String, required: true },  
},
{ optimisticConcurrency: true, versionKey: 'versionKey'})

const schemaTwo = new mongoose.Schema({
  BusinessName: { type: String, required: true },
  BusinessId: { type: String, required: true }
},
{ optimisticConcurrency: true, versionKey: 'versionKey'})
```

A document already exists in mongodb based on SchemaOne.
I need to be able to replace what exists in mongo db with data based on schema two, so not just replacing the field data but the entire schema. So if my current data is

```
{
  "_id": "12345",
  "FirstName": "John",
  "LastName": "Doe",
}
```

The new data should become:

```
{
  "_id": "12345",
  "BusinessName": "John Doe Plumbing",
  "BusinessId": "PB1234"
}
```

Note the same _Id, this is NOT a new record.
I am using the document.save() function because I’m using the concurrency feature build into mongoose.

Any ideas on how I might be able to do this?

I've tried document.overwrite() but since the document is based on SchemaOne, I get errors when saving. Remember, I need to use the save() instead of Model statics because the Mongoose concurrency logic doesn't work with those without having to use middleware (which only halfway works).

Any tips are welcome

Comment: I believe your use-case might be a good candidate for the Schema Design `Schema Versioning`.  This is a concept, not a tactical implementation, and not using any specific frameworks (like mongoose).  As such it may not directly help your current need.  Regardless of the framework, when you have a large database (i.e., more than several TB) changing the schema en-mass may no longer be a viable option, and this is where the Schema Versioning Schema Pattern really shines.  https://www.mongodb.com/blog/post/building-with-patterns-the-schema-versioning-pattern

Comment: So, looking at your current need, I could see where your code has schema definitions for both schema versions - the original, and the new version (version 2).  With that, an adapter could be created that converts from old to new, then simply issue a save() command.

Comment: In a OO world, the second schema could inherit from the first with some overrides.